# How to find all users with execute rights on a stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

...using SQL Server 2008 R2. I know how to find all objects a user has rights to, but how do I find all accounts that have execute rights on a particular object

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Below query observed from [How Can we find user have Execute Right on SP](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/44972/how-can-we-find-user-have-execute-right-on-sp-.html) will help you get the required information (Not tested .. so minor tweak may be required).

```
SELECT
s.name AS SchemaName,
o.name AS ObjectName,
dp.name AS PrincipalName,
dperm.type AS PermissionType,
dperm.permission_name AS PermissionName,
dperm.state AS PermissionState,
dperm.state_desc AS PermissionStateDescription
FROM sys.objects o
INNER JOIN sys.schemas s on o.schema_id = s.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.database_permissions dperm ON o.object_id = dperm.major_id
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals dp 
ON dperm.grantee_principal_id = dp.principal_id
WHERE
dperm.class = 1 --object or column
AND
dperm.type = 'EX'
AND 
dp.name = 'Specific_username'
AND
o.name = 'specific_object_name'
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify whether you want it through T-SQL or Management Studio. For T-SQL you already have answer, for Management Studio just right-click the object (e.g. table, stored procedure), click Properties, and then select Permissions tab. Don't miss the blue links "View schema permissions", "View database permissions", "View server permissions".

Comment: technically this would work, but you would have to individually add every user, db role and app role and that could number in the hundreds